# Will this hardware work well with Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware

I am preparing to make a significant investment into a new desktop computer. It will be used for work and play. I would like to see if any embers of the community have used any of the components and if anyone can let me know if these will work ok with Ubuntu.

The system is to support 3 screens as one giant desktop rather than 3 separate desktops. Windows should be able to be moved from screen to screen.

If anyone can suggest superior alternatives(and why they would be superior) that would also be apprecaited

Here then are the components I am buying

- Intel Core I5-760 (2.80GHZ)/8MB L3 Cache LGA1156 Processor
- CI-EVGA P55 LE Motherboard
- 2 Seagate 1Terabyte SATA Hard Drives
- Liteon IHAS-224 24x SATA Lightscribe DVDRW
- CI-EVGA GTX465 1GB DDR5 256Bit Dual DVI HDMI Videocard
- Creative SB X-FI Xtreme Audio (sound card)

  - will a sound card enhance music/movie audio or is it a waste?
- 3 LG 20" (possibly larger) LED (1600/900) %MS/DVI Widescreen

  - Are LED better than LCD?
  - How large a screen is 'to large' when it comes to work (I am a web programmer)
- DLINK DWA-525 150MBPS PCI Wireless Network Adapter
- Need good advice on a quality webcam that will work without difficulty on Ubuntu
- Need good advice on a brand of PC speakers that gives exceptional sound quliaty

I should say, I am not overly familiar with the innards of a PC so I have no idea if I have been oversold. I am also limited on the parts I can get (for example the sound card is the only sound card that shop had in stock) though I can order parts if I know what to order.

I need to be able to

- Have a multiscreen (3 screen) setup with the ability to move windows between all 3 screens
- Run compiz fusion
- Listen to music
- Watch Movies/DVD
- Write code

Answer (score 2):

The wireless N card will only work at G speeds in 10.10 currently, but once they fix that it should work at N speeds.  You shouldn't have compatibility problems with any of the other stuff you mentioned.  It is really outside the scope of this site to ask for general hardware advice, but I'll give you just a little anyway:

The core I5 is awesome, really the best "bang for your buck" if you ask me.

eVGA is a junk brand in my opinion.  I've had 2 of their video cards fail, one with exploded capacitors.  Their support is not helpful about it either.

Dedicated sound cards are pointless for most people.  The onboard audio is usually more than good enough (and has digital outputs) on modern motherboards.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I do understand what you mean about hardware advice and my main issue is workability with ubuntu. Is there a site that lists things like webcams that work with Ubuntu (I know there is one for printers)